# Jquery Multiple Divs

Tags: jquery, html

This is just a sample, my program I am writing jQuery seems to be the better route with some of the features I am using. Anyways this is the issue. On my second div I click the edit button I want to alert the value of the text box when I click the edit button.

Yes this might be duplicate, however the answer from other stack questions have said for me to use the class instead of Id. Which I have, however the jquery only affects the first div. When I click edit on the first div it alerts 251. But when i click edit on the 2nd div it alerts 251 i want it to alert 351. Thanks Stack.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.editdet').click (function() {
    alert($('.addet').val());  
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "newbox">
<form class = "something">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="addet" class = "addet"  value="251"/>
      <input type="button" id="editdet" class = "editdet"  value="Edit"/>
    </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
<br>

<div class = "newbox">
<form class = "something">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="addet" class = "addet"  value="351"/>
      <input type="button" id="editdet" class = "editdet"  value="Edit"/>
    </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: invalid markup same ids are repeated.

Comment: should i not have the ids in the input then? Only use class?

Comment: absolutely................! ids are unique for each element regardless of inputs or divs or tables etc.

Comment: You can have ID, but they must be unique in the whole web page. You could for example do `id="addet1"` and then `id="addet2"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `$('.addet')` is a collection of all the elements with the class name `addet`.

Then when you're doing `.val()` on the collection, it is grabbing the first value in the collection, which is the first one on the page, and therefore `251`

You need to get the `addet` that is relative to the `editdet` you've clicked on. You can achieve this with the [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) function:

```
$('.editdet').click (function() {
    alert($(this).prev('.addet').val());  
});
```

which will get the previous element.

Wherever your element is, you need to traverse the DOM structure relative to where the current element (`$(this)`) is.

[Some helpful jQuery functions for traversing the DOM structure](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

Comment: when i use this it alerts undefined. I think by putting the 

    <tr><td><input></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><input></td></tr> 
It causes it not to work

Comment: @BrandonC As I said, you need to traverse the DOM tree from the position of the element you've clicked. In this case you could do: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.addet').val();`. That will find the closest `tr` element and the find the `.addet` element within it.

Comment: Thank you very very much! I am quite new to this jquery business haha!

Comment: Hopefully last question, if i wanted to revalue that 351 to a different number and then alert that different number would i Just after the val() = the new value?

Comment: jQuery has some fantastic [API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) where you can find these things out yourself quicker and easier than asking Stack Overflow ;). [This bit in particular](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) will answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. I guess given my example with the this closest tr the find, just finds the value of the addet and alerts it, but to revalue the addet I guess that documentation doesnt make sense in this particular scenario

Comment: Question for you would there be any particular time that the this.closest wouldnt work in a javascript function? 

Thanks

Comment: @BrandonC this.closest or $(this).closest? The latter should always work, the prior should only work if "this" is a jQuery object.

Comment: I found my culprit. 

Is there anyway to use the click function of jquery to execute when a onclick javascript function is clicked? 

That way i dont have to click twice?

Comment: @BrandonC I don't understand what you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes I have an example except how do i post code in a commend?

Comment: I cant get the jquery to work in jsfiddle but here is the link. Basically when the user clicks the add button I want the edit button to disappeart. Right now in my program I have to click it twice. jsfiddle.net/sh7jsawy/1

Comment: @BrandonC You don't need the onclick at all. The click listener does that for you: https://jsfiddle.net/sh7jsawy/5/

Comment: This little program I posted is a smaller version of a larger on I am working on. So i posted the larger program on js fiddle. The bottom portion where it says check details information when the user clicks add detail it does this javascript function and then what i would like to do with it is blow away the div with the class detinfo and then repopulates it with the ajax return if that makes sense. Sorry I am completely new to all of this java jquery business.

Comment: I could keep using javascript but I am not sure how to change the parentnode so can repopulate a different div with the information

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can't have similar ID.
The second things is you don't target properly your value.

What you need to use is **Sibiling/Previous Selector**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.editdet').click (function() {
    alert($(this).prev().val());  
});
});
```

In this specific case shall work

Comment: yes it does thanks! However i notice that if the <input> is in its own td if that makes sense. I wish i knew how to do the code in a comment. 

How would i go about using your example to make that work?
Thanks Baldrani

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<input onclick="edit()" type="button" id="editdet" class = "editdet"  value="Edit"/>
```

with

```
<script>
  function edit() {
    alert($(this).prev().val());  
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with this code:

```
<script>
    function edit() {
        alert($(this).parent().find(".addet").val());  
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$(".addet").each(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: This does work however when i click either button it alerts both values of the divs.